# Backbone.js initializing multiple router.js files

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, backbone-routing

I am using Backbone.js require.js underscore.js to build an application. In my javascript, i have my mainrouter.js file which deals with the menu selection.

The application is broken into several sections and i wanted to have a sectionRouter.js file per section.

For some reason, when trying to load one sectionRouter.js, i get the following error

> TypeError: SectionRouter is undefined

This is the code of my mainApplication.js file

```
define([ 
     'jquery', 
     'underscore', 
     'backbone', 
     'mainRouter', // Request mainRouter.js 
     'bootstrap',
     'sectionRouter'  // this is the
 ], function($, _, Backbone, Router,SectionRouter){ 
var initialize = function(){ // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
    Router.initialize();
    initializeAnalytics();
    //Initiate a new history and controller class
    Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
    Backbone.emulateJSON = true;           
    Backbone.history.start();                
}; 

var initializeAnalytics = function(){
    SectionRouter.initialize();
};

var initializeAll = function(){
    initialize();
    initializeAnalytics();
};

return { 
    initialize: initialize
};  
});
```

Part of the sectionRouter:

```
 var SectionRouter= Backbone.Router.extend({
            //restfulUrl:"http://localhost:8080/myapp/", //This is the application service 
                            //Routes tell the app what to do
            routes:{
                "analytics/consumptions":"consumptionsActions",
                "analytics/contents":"contentsActions",
                "analytics/users":"usersAction"                    
            }               
        });

 var initialize = function (){              
            var sectionConsoleRouter= new SectionRouter;                
            //map consumptionsAction routing
            sectionConsoleRouter.on('route:consumptionsActions', function(){                    
                SeriesStorage(url to call);                  
             });
   };

  return { 
            initialize: initialize
        };
```

Can you tell me if it is possible to load the mainRouter.js and the other sectionRouter.js files together please.

**EDIT**

Is it possible to initialize the sectionRouter inside the mainRouter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added bootstrap to your list of define function parameters, but the list doesn't match the modules in your require array. So SectionRouter doesn't have a value (which is why you're getting "undefined").

Try:

```
define([ 
     'jquery', 
     'underscore', 
     'backbone', 
     'mainRouter', // Request mainRouter.js 
     'sectionRouter'  // this is the
     'bootstrap'
 ], function($, _, Backbone, Router,SectionRouter, Bootstrap){
```

There are probably other things to improve what you're trying to achieve but this will answer the question you've asked here.

Comment: bootstrap is being used only for the css purpose.  For now, i have not being using any bootstrap functions.. I try to add it and tell you

Comment: You can still use it - it's just your parameters to your define function don't match the items in your required modules array (compare my example with yours above)